# Accidental Git Commit All Files Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, git, commit, xcode5

**Background**

I use the git source control interface provided by Xcode.  Typically, I edit several files, then commit only a subset of related files at a time.  To exclude some files from a particular commit, I simply uncheck the checkbox next to it in the editor.  Rather than click the commit button, I usually use the key combination Command + Return, which commits and dismisses the window.

**Problem**

Since I began using Xcode 5, there have been several cases where Xcode commits all files, regardless of which files I have checked or unchecked.  I cannot figure out if I am pressing some other key combination that does this, or if this is just a bug in Xcode 5.  Anyone having this problem?

Comment: Xcode 5 is still under NDA and probably have some issues. Pay attention for the Git settings there..

Comment: It just happened to me. Very annoying.  I hope this question gets answered, until then, I'm sticking with the CLI.

Comment: This still occurs for me at random intervals.  I have absolutely no idea what is triggering it.  Makes no difference whether I use a key combo to commit, or press the "Commit x files" button with the mouse.  Just to be clear, it could say "Commit 2 files" and end up committing 5 files when pressed.

Comment: I also had such kind of behaviour when working with XCode. Now i'm managing my git repo with the Terminal and i get much more control on what i'm doing. That's probably not what you want as answer but it's really a best practice in my opinion.